# Alice knows $x+y$, and Bob knows $x^2+y^2$, for some integers $y\leq x\leq 25$. They alternate "I don't know the numbers" six times; then Bob knows.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, game-theory

I have this numbers teaser:

> There exists 2 integers $x $ & $ y$, such that $x\geq y$.
>
> Alice knows the value of $x+y$, and Bob knows the value of $x^2 + y^2$.
>
> The following conversation happens between Bob and Alice.
>
> Bob: I don't know the numbers
>
> Alice: I don't know the numbers
>
> Bob: I don't know the numbers
>
> Alice: I don't know the numbers
>
> Bob: I don't know the numbers
>
> Alice: I don't know the numbers
>
> Bob: I know the numbers.
>
> What are the values of $x$ and $y$ ?

I have been also told that $x$ and $y$ do not exceed 25 each, and that there is a unique answer to this problem.

Does anyone know how it is solved?

---

Approach: I did try to solve it as this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4244093/965433) suggested, however i couldn't reach a specific value at the end. (Please note this code was written in iPy)

Here is my code:

```
from itertools import product
options = [(x,y,x+y,x**2+y**2) for x,y in product(range(1,26),repeat=2) if x >= y]
for i in range(100):
    if i%2==0: #Bob
        j=3
    else: #Alice
        j=2
    op = []
    for o in options:
        if len([k for k in options if k[j]==o[j]])>1:
            op.append(o)
    options = op
    
    display(len(options),i)
    if len(options) <= 1:
        break
display(options,i)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This information helps us provide better-aimed answers for you.

Comment: If you know the answer and want to share a challenge, there is the Puzzle Solving Stack Exchange site.

Comment: The trick to these kind of questions is to note that each "I don't know" implies there is more than one possible pair of numbers, so restricting the cases the other person needs to consider. For example you cannot have $x^2+y^2 = 5$ as otherwise Bob would know the answer is $2$ and $1$

Comment: Your program needs to implement the posted answer's last bullet: verify that when Bob says he knows (x,y) (i.e. when i=6), only one of the remaining options has a unique sum-of-squares. You can run such a modified version of your program online [here](https://tio.run/##XVDRasMwDHzPVwjGwG5DSVPoQ8CF7TdCHtJW2dykluc4kHx9ajtd3M1gIevudJL1ZL9JHea5MXQHadFYoq4HeddkLGhD1@FiE9JWkupBQMnGdErHrbubTb6dXODQkAFXBql@FczU6gvZPs2PPDWosbbCEWUDI5wETFXiNdIrnsws40UC7jiOfM@FyAp4@6RzqPlzE4eQY9ejgz46ecEXMA85aT9jFfJByZ8B49s7knd8blOsamfZoWJlGzjtC8dDbXmrhCAXK37aR9Xit6u1RnVlxFcgTPiHtozyjxo/lXQorOuDEHCMHbSRyrKlR3Q5G6zbeX4A).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x$ and $y$ are integers in the range $1$ to $25$... Hint:

- There are ${25 \choose 2}+25=325$ ways to choose $x$ and $y$ (as a pair). List them all, and for each of them calculate what would be Alice's knowledge ($x+y$) and what would be Bob' knowledge ($x^2+y^2$)
- Now, because Bob does not know outright the solution, cross out the pairs which have a unique value of $x^2+y^2$
- Now, because Alice does not know outright the solution (but she knows Bob didn't know it - so she has presumably done the previous step in her mind), we can look at the remaining pairs and cross out those that have a unique value of $x+y$.
- Now, Bob's done the same, but he still doesn't know the solution, so we can go on and cross out again all the remaining pairs with a unique $x^2+y^2$
- And so on ... following the conversation between Alice and Bob.
- Eventually, Bob knows the numbers, so the solution is one of the remaining pairs with unique $x^2+y^2$. Hopefully at that stage there will be only one such pair.

It is a finite (though not exactly small) problem, so instead of doing it by hand, leave it to a computer to comb through those pairs.

Comment: There are 325 pairs to consider (not 300, because the elements may be equal).

Comment: @r.e.s. Oops, my bad. Fixed.